# Работа с формами в asp net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Реализую процесс добавления объекта в корзину, но при добавлении корзина остается пустой.
Модель выглядит следующим образом

```
public class Cart
{
    
   private List<CartModel> Cart = new List<CartModel>();
    public void AddToCart(CartModel CartModel)
    {
        Cart.Add(CartModel);
    }
    public IEnumerable<CartModel> Lines
    {
            get { return Cart; }
    }
}
```

Контроллер добавления и определения сеанса

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {
        ProductViewModel product = db.Specifications
                                        .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);
        if(product != null)
        {
            CartModel cart = new CartModel{
            Product = product,
            NumberProduct = 1
            };
            GetCart().AddToCart(cart);
        }
        return  Redirect("/Cart");
    }
    public Cart GetCart()
    {
        OperationCart operationCart = HttpContext.Session.Get< Cart >("OperationCart"); //(CartViewModel)Session["Cart"];
        if (operationCart == null)
        {
            operationCart = new Cart();
            HttpContext.Session.Set< Cart >( "OperationCart" , operationCart);
        }
        return operationCart;
    }
```

Контроллер отображения корзины

```
public IActionResult Cart()
    {
        return View(new CartViewModel
        {
            Cart = GetCart()
        });
    }
```

Вот как выглядит форма

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart","Cart"))
{
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id);
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Добавить в корзину" />
}
```

При открывании корзины она остается пуста.Никаких ошибок нет в чем проблема не ясно.
Спасибо

Comment: Я вижу , что вы считываете пустую корзину из сессии, обновляете её, но где вы её обратно обновленную в сессию записываете?

Comment: @tym32167 Как можно исправить просто GetCart после добавления(GetCart().AddToCart(cart);) остается пустым.

Comment: Вам надо, чтобы обновлённая версия корзины сохранилась в сессию, так? А где вы ее сохраняете в коде? Нигде. Вот и не сохраняется ничего.

Comment: @tym32167 Как я могу сохранить?Вроде метод GetCart предназначен для этого.

Comment: Метод «получить корзину» сохраняет пустую корзину в сессию если там не было никакой корзины. Вам, после ваших изменений корзины, надо эту корзину снова сохранить в сессию.

Comment: @tym32167,  `HttpContext.Session.Set< Cart >( "OperationCart" , operationCart);`  эта строка разве не созраняет корзину с   сессией ?Если нет то где это сделать (в методе добавления в корзину) или в другом месте?

Comment: Поглядите внимательно что перед этой строкой. Там создается пусткая корзина. То есть эта строка сохраняет пустую корзину. Просто для понимания - вам надо снова сохранять корзину после каждого изменения в ней.

Comment: Чтобы больше понять, что происзодит - вы сохраняете не корзину, а её копию. То есть факт, что корзина была сохранена когда то в сессию не означает, что изменения, что вы в корзину внесете после этого, как то сами сохранятся в сессию. Надо вызывать сохранение самому. Как с базой данных - прочитали данные, изменили, надо сохранить.

Comment: @tym32167, Если я правильно понял, нужно в методе добавления AddToCart  добавить сохранения сессии `HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("cart",cart);`,вместо cart передать туда список из модели operationcart.Верно?

Comment: Не надо спрашивать такие вопросы, ведь их быстрее проверить самому. Но я бы написал `var cart = GetCart(); cart.AddCart(..); HttpContext.Session.Set< Cart >( "OperationCart" , cart );`

Comment: ну или раз у вас есть метод `GetCart()`, логично бы иметь метод `SetCart(OperationCart cart)`

Comment: @tym32167,Спасибо,работает